# Fetch next n numbers from a function

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function which will return an array. Below is the snippet :

```js
function FetchNNumbers(Size, Nbr, NextNNumbers){
  arr = new Array();
  LValue = Nbr + NextNNumbers;
  for(i = Nbr; i<LValue; i++){
  if(LValue>Size){
    Nbr = Nbr - (LValue-Size);
    LValue= Nbr + NextNNumbers;
    arr.push(Nbr);
    Nbr++;
    } else {
      arr.push(Nbr);
      Nbr++;
     }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(FetchNNumbers(10,7,3)) // [7,8,9]     --> Correct and Expected Output
console.log(FetchNNumbers(10,7,5)) // [5,6,7]     --> Incorrect Output
                      // [5,6,7,8,9] --> Expected Output
```

I am not able to identify where loop is going wrong?

Expectations from this function:-

1. As per the value of `NextNNumbers`. This function should return array of next N numbers starting from `Nbr`
2. As in my 2nd example, where value of `NextNNumbers` exceeds the value of `Size`. In this case function should pick last 5 values.

Comment: Don't use `Number` as your own variable name, and declare variables like `arr` and `LastValue`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the function? You showed some expected and unexpected outputs, but you didn't explain what the function is actually supposed to do.

Comment: Why did you use the `Number++` you are in for loop nor in while loop - also `Number` is a method of js why did you use it as argument

Comment: The lines `      arr.push(Number);      Number++;` can be factored out of the `if` clause.

Comment: @Pointy and TKoL I have edited my query with respective things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the invalid point here is the start value.
Could you try with this?

```
function FetchNNumbers(Size, Number, NextNNumbers){
  arr = new Array();
  // LastValue = Number + NextNNumbers;
  
  let start = Size - NextNNumbers;
  
  for(i = start; i<Size; i++){
    if(LastValue>Size){
        Number = Number - (LastValue-Size);
        LastValue= Number + NextNNumbers;
        arr.push(Number);
        Number++;
    } else {
      arr.push(Number);
      Number++;
     }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked. Only change I had to do was uncomment line number 3. As value of `LastValue` is used to Calculate values of `Number` and `LastValue` inside `if statement`. But it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize `i` out of `for` based on your conditions:

`var i = LValue > Size ? Nbr - (LValue - Size) : Nbr;`

Try this one:

```js
  function FetchNNumbers(Size, Nbr, NextNNumbers) {
                arr = new Array();
                LValue = Nbr + NextNNumbers;
                var i = LValue > Size ? Nbr - (LValue - Size) : Nbr;
                for (;i < LValue; i++) {
                    if (LValue > Size) {
                        Nbr = Nbr - (LValue - Size);
                        LValue = Nbr + NextNNumbers;
                        arr.push(Nbr);
                        Nbr++;
                    } else {
                        arr.push(Nbr);
                        Nbr++;
                    }
                }
                console.log(arr);
                return arr;
            }
            
            FetchNNumbers(10, 7, 3) 
            FetchNNumbers(10, 7, 5)
```

Comment: This was indeed a clever answer... Upvoting for the approach..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your function is to count up until a number is reached but I can't really tell from your explanation so the best I can do is I changed your function to count from one number up by n using your for statement:

```
function FetchNNumbers(StartVal, CountBy){
 let arr = new Array();
 for(i = 0; i<CountBy; i++){
  arr.push(StartVal + i);
 }
 return arr;
}
FetchNNumbers(5,5) //5,6,7,8,9
```

if this doesn't do what you wanted then you have to specify

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `i = Nbr` in the loop, this sets your i to 7 and it runs from 7-9 and ends the loop so you have only 3 numbers inserted in the array in the second case so @user1520112 answer will work.